# Loop through child pages when already on a child page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, parent-child

I have a property site where the parent is a development, and the children are plots within the development.

On the development page I use the following code to display all child pages (plot pages) of that development.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
        'orderby'       => 'plot_number',
        'order'         => 'ASC'
     );     
    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );    
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) :  
    ?>
        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        //CONTENT GOES HERE

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I want to display the same thing (all the child pages of the development) but on the child pages themselves. Essentially I need to check if the page has a parent then loop through the child pages...

Any ideas?

Comment: Simple. Just get out the current page parent number with `wp_get_post_parent_id`, and in the query, get the childs of it.

Comment: Thanks for this, are you able to provide an example please?

Comment: The page-list plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-list/) does this. You could either use it, or download it to learn how it works.

Comment: Thank you Ollie. I'm keen to learn the code behind this so would prefer the php but at least I know there's a fallback option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the exact same query as above, with one slight modification. Just one note before I continue, if you use `WP_Query`, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()`, not `wp_reset_query()`. The latter is used with `query_posts` which in any case you should **never** use

To get the post parent, you can use `$post->post_parent`. This will return the ID of the current page's parent. If the ID returns `0`, it means that this is a top level page. So you would also want to check if `$post->post_parent` is not `0` before running your query, or you would get back all posts regardless if the current page is a top level page

Example

```
<?php

global $post;

if( 0 != $post->post_parent ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'property',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
        'orderby'       => 'plot_number',
        'order'         => 'ASC'
     );     
    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );    
    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) :  
    ?>
        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

        //CONTENT GOES HERE

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; 

} 
?>
```

Just one other thing that I've picked up now, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` before `endif` but after `endwhile`

Comment: This looks perfect. I will try it out soon and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: No problem, take your time and test it thouroughly :-)

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly and makes sense to me. Thank you for this and the tip for resetting. Every day is a school day!

Comment: Hahaha, that is true, I also still have tons to learn and learn everyday :-) Enjoy